# ReduceRegion not giving GEE data

Tags: google-earth-engine, reduceregion, hyperion

I'm using reduceRegion on Hyperion data using the GEE Python API. I have a FeatureCollection, where, for each feature, I find the average of the required field for the whole feature, for a single median image from the Hyperion dataset. My code for Hyperion data extraction is working in the GEE JavaScript API, but is not working using the Python API. In the Python API, I am able to extract data for all of the other fields from other datasets, such as NDVI etc.

My code is below (table is my region of interest):

```
dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('JRC/GWIS/GlobFire/v2/FinalPerimeters').filterBounds(table).filter(ee.Filter.intersects(".geo", ee.Geometry.Point(0,0)).Not()).filter(ee.Filter.area(60000, 3000000000)).filter(ee.Filter.gte('IDate', 1483228800000))
dataset.size()

soilmoisture = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/SMAP/SPL3SMP_E/005").filterBounds(table)
terrandvi = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD09GA_006_NDVI').filterBounds(table)
era5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR").filterBounds(table)
landcover = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MCD12Q1").filterBounds(table)
dem = ee.Image("NASA/NASADEM_HGT/001").clip(table)

dataset2 = ee.ImageCollection('EO1/HYPERION').filterBounds(table)
mediano = ee.Image(dataset2.median()).add(0)
#mediano = mediano.clip(table)

def compute(feature):
    keepProperties = ['IDate']
  
    final = ee.Feature(feature.geometry()).copyProperties(feature, keepProperties)
    ccords = feature.geometry().centroid().coordinates()
    initial_date = ee.Date(feature.get('IDate'))
  
    start = ee.Number(ee.Feature(feature).get('IDate')).subtract(604800000)
    lc_start = ee.Number(ee.Feature(feature).get('IDate')).subtract(31560000000)
    end = ee.Number(ee.Feature(feature).get('IDate'))

    geom = ee.Feature(feature).geometry()

    ##var smam = soilmoisture.filterDate(start, end).select('soil_moisture_am').mean();
    ndvi = terrandvi.filterDate(start, end).select('NDVI').mean()
    landc = landcover.filterDate(lc_start, end).select('LC_Prop1').mean()
    elev = dem.select('elevation').clip(feature.geometry())#.reproject(crs = 'SR-ORG:6974', scale = 9000)
    #aslope = ee.Terrain.products(dem).select(['aspect', 'slope']).clip(feature.geometry())
    era5l = era5.filterDate(start, end).select(['dewpoint_temperature_2m', 'skin_temperature', 'total_precipitation_sum', 'u_component_of_wind_10m', 'v_component_of_wind_10m', 'volumetric_soil_water_layer_1']).mean().clip(feature.geometry()).reproject(crs = 'SR-ORG:6974', scale = 9000)
    ndmi2 = mediano.normalizedDifference(['B047', 'B145']).clip(feature.geometry())#.reproject(crs = 'SR:ORG:6974', scale = 9000)
    ndlma2 = mediano.normalizedDifference(['B211', 'B134']).clip(feature.geometry())#.reproject(crs = 'SR:ORG:6974', scale = 9000)
    ndlma = mediano.normalizedDifference(['B122', 'B157']).clip(feature.geometry())#.reproject(crs = 'SR:ORG:6974', scale = 9000)

    i1600 = mediano.select('B145')
    i820 = mediano.select('B047')
    msi = i1600.divide(i820).clip(feature.geometry())#.reproject(crs = 'SR:ORG:6974', scale = 9000)
    
    #var reduced_smam = smam.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry: geom, scale: 9000, maxPixels: 1e9});
    reduced_ndmi = ndmi2.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = geom, scale = 9000, crs = 'EPSG:4326', maxPixels = 1e9)
    reduced_ndlma = ndlma.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = geom, scale = 9000, crs = 'EPSG:4326', maxPixels = 1e9)
    reduced_ndlma2 = ndlma2.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = geom, scale = 9000, crs = 'EPSG:4326', maxPixels = 1e9)
    reduced_msi = msi.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = geom, scale = 9000, crs = 'EPSG:4326', maxPixels = 1e9)
    reduced_ndvi = ndvi.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = geom, scale = 9000, maxPixels = 1e9)
    reduced_landc = landc.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = geom, scale = 9000, maxPixels = 1e9)
    reduced_elev = elev.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = geom, scale = 9000, maxPixels = 1e9)
    #reduced_aslope = aslope.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = geom, scale = 9000, maxPixels = 1e9)
    reduced_era5l = era5l.reduceRegion(reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry = geom, scale = 9000, maxPixels = 1e9)

    final = final.set('ndmi', reduced_ndmi.get('nd'))
    final = final.set('ndlma', reduced_ndlma.get('nd'))
    final = final.set('ndlma2', reduced_ndlma2.get('nd'))
    final = final.set('msi', reduced_msi.get('B145'))
    #final = final.set('soil_moisture_am', reduced_smam.get('soil_moisture_am'));
    final = final.set('ndvi', reduced_ndvi.get('NDVI'))
    final = final.set('longitude', ccords.get(0))
    final = final.set('latitude', ccords.get(1))
    final = final.set('month', initial_date.get('month'))
    final = final.set('day', initial_date.get('day'))
    final = final.set('land_cover', reduced_landc.get('LC_Prop1'))
    final = final.set('elevation', reduced_elev.get('elevation'))
    #final = final.set('aspect', reduced_aslope.get('aspect'))
    #final = final.set('slope', reduced_aslope.get('slope'))
    final = final.set('dewpoint_temperature', reduced_era5l.get('dewpoint_temperature_2m'))
    final = final.set('skin_temperature', reduced_era5l.get('skin_temperature'))
    final = final.set('precipitation', reduced_era5l.get('total_precipitation_sum'))
    final = final.set('wind_u', reduced_era5l.get('u_component_of_wind_10m'))
    final = final.set('wind_v', reduced_era5l.get('v_component_of_wind_10m'))
    final = final.set('soil_water', reduced_era5l.get('volumetric_soil_water_layer_1'))
    return final

final_dataset = dataset.map(lambda feature: compute(feature))#.filter(ee.Filter.gte('ndvi', 0))
```

When I try doing `final_dataset.first()` or converting the FeatureCollection to a pandas dataframe, I get all columns except for MSI/NDLMA/NDLMA2/NDMI. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: This code is incomplete and unrunnable.

Comment: I have fixed the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your dataset doesn't intersect any hyperion images, so the reduceRegion produces no result.  Hyperion doesn't have wall-to-wall coverage; there are only 82,000 images, and they only cover a small fraction of the land surface.

[image]

Comment: Weirdly, when using the JavaScript API, I was getting data for roughly 1/10 of the features in the dataset. Now, I'm getting none.